# Complex modulus inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

The following problem is from 'Applied Complex Variables for Scientists and Engineers' by Yue Kuen Kwok.

Suppose f(z) is analytic on and inside the unit circle $|z|=1$, and that Re $f(z) > 0,$ with $f(0) = \alpha > 0$.

Show that

$$\left| \frac{f(z)-\alpha}{f(z)+\alpha} \right| \leq |z| \hspace{5mm} \text{   and   } \hspace{5mm} |f'(0)| \leq 2 \alpha.$$

Attempt: for the first inequality, if we write $f(z)$ as $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, we have 
$$LHS = \frac{(u-\alpha)^2 +v^2}{(u+\alpha)^2 +v^2} \leq \frac{u^2 - 2u \alpha + \alpha^2 +v^2}{u^2+2u\alpha + \alpha^2 + v^2} \leq \frac{u^2 + 2u \alpha + \alpha^2 +v^2}{u^2+2u\alpha + \alpha^2 + v^2} = 1,$$ 
meaning that is easy enough to show the LHS is less than or equal to one, but I cannot seem to make any modifications to show it is less than $|z|$, or think of any other way to do it... if anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful. I suspect the maximum modulus principle applies somehow...

Note: this is from a chapter which covers Cauchy int. thm., max mod principle, and mean value theorem *only*, and so Schwarz/Harnack/other inequalities should not be employed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Set 
$$
g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{f(z)+a},
$$
and show that $g$ is analytic in the unit disk, $|g(z)|\le 1$ and $g(0)=0$.

Step 2. Apply Schwarz Lemma to $g$, to obtain that 
$$|g(z)|\le |z| \quad \text{and}\quad  |g'(0)|\le 1.
$$

Step 3. Translate the inequalities above for $g$, as inequalities  for $f$.